# Use one list to populate another and save the 2nd with additional information

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The title might be a little confusing but here is what I am trying to do.

I have one list

```
  $scope.List = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Apples"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oranges"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Peaches"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Coconuts"
  }, ];
```

And I have it so when I click on a fruit it gets added to a 2nd list but then I am able to specify Amount and Price.

What I am trying to do is save this 2nd list WITH the amount and price information into an array (called MyList) and I am 100% stumped.

Here is what I have so far it is also on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6k5ZzfBBRa8IOerGlK4V)  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.List = [{
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Apples"
      }, {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Oranges"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Peaches"
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Coconuts"
      }, ];

      $scope.NewList = [];

      $scope.MyList = {};

      $scope.addfood = function(fruit) {
        $scope.NewList.push(fruit);
        $scope.List.splice($scope.List.indexOf(fruit), 1);
      };

      $scope.returnfood = function(newFruit) {
        $scope.List.push(newFruit);
        $scope.NewList.splice($scope.NewList.indexOf(newFruit), 1);
      };

      $scope.save = function(Nfood) {
        $scope.MyList = angular.copy(Nfood);
      };


    }
  ]);
```

Here is the HTML

```
<body ng-app="formExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p ng-repeat="food in List">
      <a ng-click="addfood(food)">
            {{food.name}}
        </a>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="Nfood in NewList">
      {{Nfood.name}}
      <input ng-model="Nfood.Amount" type="number" class="form-control" min="0"><span class="input-group-addon">Amount</span>
      <input ng-model="Nfood.Price" type="number" class="form-control" min="0"><span class="input-group-addon">Price</span>
      <button ng-click="returnfood(Nfood)">REMOVE</button>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="save(Nfood)">Save</button>


  </div>

  <pre>
    {{MyList | json}}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0PucpWiRyVTis2PO6q8T?p=preview)

at the first you stored your button in place where it cant access your vars, I mean outside of controller, also you should create array for MyList not an object and after use push function to add elements in it

```
<div ng-repeat="Nfood in NewList">
            {{Nfood.name}}
            <input ng-model="Nfood.Amount" type="number" class="form-control" min="0"><span
                class="input-group-addon">Amount</span>
            <input ng-model="Nfood.Price" type="number" class="form-control" min="0"><span
                class="input-group-addon">Price</span>
        <button ng-click="returnfood(Nfood)">REMOVE</button>
        <button ng-click="save(Nfood)">Save</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: So When I run the working example I dont see <pre>
    {{MyList}}
</pre> get populated with anything.

Comment: so this does work and did answer my question.  Probably because I didnt ask it well.  But is there a way to have the save() capture the entire list?

Comment: you have three list, and you can access each of them in that scope,  if you dont have another question please also vote up mu answer :) thanks